# main...chunk.js load error on custom domain after purge on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm hosting React App as static website on Azure Storage with CDN.
I see that when I'm deploying new code - new functionality is present on CDN address (...azureedge.net), but on custom domain new changes sometime appears and sometimes there is still old code. New code comes in for good after about 2 days as i noticed.

I've read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint that I could use "Purge" button to refresh cache. I did it with "Purge all" checkbox and now on my custom domain i see only white screen and error in console. On azureedge.net address everything works fine with new changes. I did it about 20 minutes ago and website still doesn't work.

Do someone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: having the same here sometimes, even having a release step to purge automatically after a deployment (which is horrible) time to time I have this issue and sometimes is just for some of our users... did you found a better solution?

Comment: For me, it works even without any purges. Just waiting 10-15 mins after the deployment - and the website stabilizes automatically after the next page refresh. So the problem still exists on Azure CDN :(

Answer (score 0):

Firing "Purge" for 2nd time fixed problem.